# How to return the first item rather than the entire list, using list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm solving a problem where I must find an unique integer in a list, which is easily solvable using list.count(x). However, I'm having trouble condensing the code into one line.

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    return [x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1]
```

My code works fine, but it returns for example: `[2]` instead of `2`, or `[0.55]` instead of `0.55`.

**Is there a way to return the integer instead of the list containing the integer, using list comprehension?**

Comment: Can you share the list?

Comment: `return [x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1][0]` or `return next((x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1), None)` without creating a list.

Comment: Are there nested lists?

Comment: Why do you use a *list* comprehension *when you don't want a list*?

Comment: *"I'm having trouble condensing the code into one line"* If your shopping items don't fit into one bag, you might have to take a second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already the answers for list-comprehension -- which is a waste of resources.
Your approach, though, is valid since it makes use of everyday/beginner structures. In the same argument, I would like to suggest two things:

- avoid the redundant calls to `count()`;
- avoid the creation of a list (since all you want is one element a time).

Suppose we have the following array `arr`:

```py
> arr = [random.randint(0,9) for _ in range(10)]
> arr
[6, 7, 0, 9, 3, 3, 3, 9, 8, 8]
```

To the first point, you can create a `set` to reduce the number of *counts*:

```py
> numbers_set = set(arr)
> numbers_set
{0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Then you can have a generator with the help of our friend `filter`:

```py
> unique_numbers = filter(lambda x:arr.count(x)==1, numbers_set)
> print(next(unique_numbers))
0
> print(next(unique_numbers))
6
> print(next(unique_numbers))
7
> print(next(unique_numbers))
StopIteration:
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a *list comprehension* which produces a *list*, create a generator from which you take the first element:

```
return next(x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1)
```

This raises a `StopIteration` is no element in the list fulfils the criteria; you can instead return a default value like `None` like so:

```
return next((x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1), None)
```

It's also questionable whether it's wise to iterate the array again and again with `count`; depending on its size, that can be very inefficient. It may be more efficient to build a counter first:

```
from collections import Counter
```

```
return next(v for v, c in Counter(arr).items() if c == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that You want to return only one integer from the passed list You can change the return to

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    return [x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1][0]
```

But it will return only first element that is unique in the list. If You want to return more of them the list is better approach

Answer (score 1):

Return using indexing.

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    return [x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == 1][0]
```